# Missing styles after load them in head using php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to print my styles inline in `head` tag using php. I am almost finished, but I discovered that my styles are gone on IE8 (I assume that on earlier versions too). What I've found is that, the problem appears when 3 stylesheets are printed (no matter what order) - bootstrap.min.css, font-awesome.min.css and theme-style.css. Last one is from my template. When I comment one, or two of those, no matter which, then everything is working great (I mean the three selection above). Another fact is that if I `link` them, everything works great again.

Why do i need that? For increase my page speed.

Above I pasted my source from index.php. Example I published on [my testing website](http://ie8bts.esy.es/) where you can see how it is displayed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <?php
      $styles = '';
      $styles .= file_get_contents('bootstrap.min.css');
      $styles .= file_get_contents('theme-style.css');
      $styles .= file_get_contents('font-awesome.min.css');
      ?>

      <style type="text/css">
         <?php echo $styles; ?>
         .test1{color: #F00; background: #ccc;}.test2{color: #0F0;}.test3{color: #00F;}
      </style>

      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="/respond/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="test1">
         testing something
      </div>
      <div class="test2">
         Lorem ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="test3">
         John Doe
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to just indiviually echo them instead of first combining them into one?

Comment: And why are you doing it like that? Why not just do something normal like... `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">`

Comment: 'Why do i need that? For increase my page speed.' I think you're doing it wrong. This doesn't increase the page speed since at every request you include the whole style sheet making the page bigger in size for transferring. A webbrowser would download a linked stylesheet file once and keep it in cache so it doesn't download it again every request. That way you can keep your HTML-file smaller which gives better page speed. But yes, the first request will be kinda slow since all files need to be loaded.

Comment: @Epodax for page speed, after I paste inline source from stylesheets google insights add some points to my website

Comment: @SuperDJ it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I dread answering this... But here goes...

Page Speed by Google is only an idea. It is a concept. It is not the reality of the internet. You can very much hurt your site by including the files into the index page. Why? Because in doing so you are increasing the size of the index page. It will be increased into so large a size that it requires multiple retrievals. In doing so you will introduce a problem instead of solving one.

When a browser asks your website for information several things happen. I am going to break them down into simple concepts.

Browser: Give me http://www.example.com
Server: Here is the index page:
Browser: I see I need to grab the page and it is 200K because the style sheets are part of the page. Give me the index page.
Server: Here you go:
  Hops between the server and the index page: We see this data is big. We are going to break it into chunks. Three of them to be exact.
Browser: Oh, jeez! Wait.. wait... wait.. Okay, now I have all three chunks. Lets render what I have!

This is why Page Speed is NOT the end all to getting good results in Google. For an example look at your competition who have the results you are trying to achieve. They might have scores of 64, 78, 82, 90... And all of them, even the 64 in RED is beating you in the results of a search.

What you could achieve is user experience that gets them to keep coming back which is probably why your competition with a 64 score is beating you.

What he is doing:

Browser: Give me index page.
Server: Here you go, but it has the style sheets linked and same with javascript.
Browser: No problem! Since they are all separate I will request them all at the same time: index.php, file1.css, file2.css, file3.css, javascript.js

Hops between them: Cool, you want a bunch of small chunks. We can route those through various open gateways between the user and the server and get them all there in less time than it would take if you included them all into the index page.

User: Ahh... everything loaded in like .8 seconds which is lighting fast!